# How to redirect the Root of an Amazon S3 Bucket created just for downloads?

Tags: amazon-s3

We have an Amazon S3 bucket setup simply for downloads (we send a lot of traffic to download pdfs etc). The issue is that anyone can access the root folder and see everything in there.

The links are setup like this:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/file-name.pdf
```

The bucket is setup to have Public Access.

The Access Control list has just "Write Objects" checked - otherwise we can't upload to it.

To make the Bucket public we have this in our permission folder:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

We'd like to tidy it up so that if anyone hits the bucket root, they get redirected to a place we choose.

I have an index.html file setup that is redirecting, however the root folder doesn't load this file by default.

Can anyone point me to the solution for this? Or if it's not possible with our current setup, what steps should I take? We already have the links right through our site so redoing the, all isn't really the best option. I have been through a lot of threads trying to find a solution for this and really appreciate any input!

Comment: Have you looked at S3 static website hosting and redirects (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html)?

Comment: This policy can't be the only thing you have set on your bucket.  Listings are denied by default, so you have changed a setting that allows this.  Check the [Bucket ACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-bucket-permissions.html) settings under Public Access.  Remove that.

Comment: Michael - sqlbot - Thank you! In Access Control List > Public access > Everyone "List Objects" was checked. It's still not redirecting, but it isn't showing all contents anymore.